# inequality, increasing and differentiation

Tags: derivatives, inequality

why does $\tan x > x$ mean $\tan x − x$ is increasing ? If the right side x is transferred to the left side, the inequality is equal to $\tan x-x>0$.

I think if the x is transferred to the left side, we need to prove that $\tan x-x>0$ for $0<x<\frac\pi2$, which means the function of $\tan x-x$ is above the $x$- axis.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsCqY.png)

Comment: Note that $f(x) > g(x)$ does **not** imply that $h(x):= f(x)-g(x)$ is increasing. For instance, consider $1/x^2 > 1/x$ in $(0,1)$ but $1/x^2 - 1/x$ is decreasing.

Comment: You're thinking of the implication going the other way.  It's not that $f(x) > g(x)$ implies $f(x) - g(x)$ is increasing; rather, it's that $f(x) - g(x)$ is (positive and) increasing implies $f(x) > g(x)$.  And hopefully that makes sense:  If the quantity $f(x) - g(x)$ is positive and growing, then one of those terms can never fall below the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'll approach with derivations.

Let $f(x)=\tan x-x$, then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-1=\tan^2x>0$ when $0<x<\frac\pi2$.

So $f(x)$ increases at that range.